# A question regarding C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I want to perform the updation of the existing record.. the way that i have paste my code here i have successfully achieved my task but i dont want to do the updation by that way actually.. i want to do such that i get the id of the customer..

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=COMPAQ-PC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gym;Integrated Security=True");
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                cn.Open();
            }
            int result = new SqlCommand("Update Customer set Customer_Name = '" + tbName.Text + "',Cell_Number = '" + tbContactNumber.Text + "',Customer_Address = '" + tbAddress.Text + "' where CustomerID = " + tbID.Text, cn).ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
            cn.Dispose();

            BindGridView();
        }

private void BindGridView()
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=COMPAQ-PC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gym;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customer", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgView_CustomerInfo.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }

private void dgView_CustomerInfo_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {

            tbID.Text = dgView_CustomerInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CustomerID"].Value.ToString();
            tbName.Text = dgView_CustomerInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Customer_Name"].Value.ToString();
            tbContactNumber.Text = dgView_CustomerInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Cell_Number"].Value.ToString();
            tbAddress.Text = dgView_CustomerInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Customer_Address"].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Please go back and edit your question to make what you're asking more clear.

Comment: Please don't use `select * from Customer`. Enumerate your columns instead. `select CustomerID, Customer_Name, Cell_Number, Customer_Address from Customer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coding Gorilla above has already given you a perfectly good answer, and I support it.

The question you'll find yourself asking about 20 minutes after this goes live is: "Hey, how did all these hackers get my data?"

The method you have above is RIPE for SQL Injection.  Read about it here: http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5DP0N1P76E.html

Don't put code like this into production.  Sanitize your inputs and use parametrized queries for your DB interactions.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is: How can I store the state of my Customer Id without putting in a text box.

There are a lot of ways to do this, I would do it using the `ViewState` like this:

```
public int CustomerId
{
   get { return (int)(ViewState["CustomerId"] ?? -1); }
   set { ViewState["CustomerId"] = value; }
}
```

You can read more about the ViewState here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx

** **EDIT** **

If you're using a Windows forms application the ViewState will not work, that's for ASP.NET.  Instead you should look at using a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) control and read up on Databind in Winforms.

Comment: This is assuming he's using ASP.NET webforms.

Comment: @coding Gorilla.. you are absolutely right, that was what i wanted to ask! thanx mate!

Comment: Yes, he didn't really specific, but if this were a winforms application or WPF or something like that, then managing state is obviously much simpler.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla.. can you please explain me the code? :/

Comment: i`m using a Winforms application

Comment: If you are using Winforms, you don't need to get the customer id back if you already had it...you can just keep it in memory.

Comment: @jeff : yeah, sorry for that.. i just did not had that in my mind!

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** use string concatenation when constructing your SQL!

Use **parameterized statements** with placeholders, and set the values using a Parameter object.